# Brewing first wine from juice need some help

Tags: wine

So i looked up a cheap way to make me self some wine, and i decided to go with cranberry juice 100% from concentrate no preservatives or anything like that in it, i started of with 1liter, i poured some sugar in too for higher abv, and put about 3grams of baking yeast, the bottle was sterile since it contained the juice in it, now it has been about 4-5 days and the wine is little bit carbonated and still too sweet for my liking, will the sugars still be converted to alcohol withing 2 weeks or so, should i use champagne yeast next batch?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have some type of alcoholic drink, but you picked a few components that can add to the challenge of a first time vitner. Cranberry is a tough juice, as stated, high in acid, can make a good wine, but will need time and possible other additives to balance the final result into something palatable.  Bread yeast will give, a "doughy" flavor, you may wish to investigate a better yeast made for fruit juices.  Also, I have made very good wine, mixing Welchs Concord & White Grape frozen concentrates, water, sugar and a champagne yeast. Simple ingredients, easily obtainable. Q

Answer (score 0):

Cranberry juice is rather acidic, so the yeast may have a hard time completing fermentation due to the acid content. However, assuming that won't be an issue, and taking into account you are using bread yeast I would expect to have fully fermented "wine" after about 3 weeks. Did you take a hydrometer reading? If you took an initial gravity reading you could periodically check the gravity and halt fermentation when you are satisfied with the alcohol content.

Hopefully that helps